# GCE LB not picking up readinessProbe URL

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I updated readiness probe in my deployment file and also specify port in ingress, service and deployment.

But my GCE Load Balancer health check is not reflecting the correct path (even I delete and recreate ingress).

Am I missing any configuration?

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: custom-app-managed-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - uat.xyz.com
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: app-gce-uat-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: custom-app-uat-managed-cert
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "uat.xyz.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: custom-app
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: custom-app
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: custom-app-gke
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: custom-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: custom-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: app-svc
      containers:
      - name: custom-app-app
        image: xxx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 80
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "80"
---
```

Comment: What is the health check actually showing?

Comment: @GariSingh the GCP LB health check path is showing the default path "/" ... 
I was expecting it should get from the pod readiness probe setting.

Comment: Hmm ... yeah ... looks like you have everything configured correctly for the inferred params to pick up the right path.   I'll see what I can find.